# How to stretch DIV's height to 100% of a table cell in IE and Firefox?

Tags: css

I know there are already similar question, but none of them could solve my problem for IE and Firefox:

The `<td>` tag has no height specification, it depends on its content (the `<div>`)
This is what I have now but works for Chrome only:

```
display:inline-block;
height:100%;
```

Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: Have you set padding, cell padding, and margins to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at this [jquery code](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/) which creates equal height divs.  As jquery is built to be cross browser friendly, it should work ok for both IE and Firefox.  You'd just have to see if creating a div inside a table does what you wanted.

Minor note to remind that tables for layout are generally considered bad but it depends on your requirement - if it's really to create a table of information that is nice and orderly rather than for website layout then it's fine.

As an alternative, you could also look at these methods for [creating tables using CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/)

Comment: Thank you Trevor, I think you forgot the link to the jQuery code.